# Filter combobox itemsource to display active values only plus the currently selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a custom combobox control used throughout an application.  I want the ItemsSource to display active items only and the currently selectedvalue even if it is not active.  I actually have it all working, but it is only working if there is a converter contained the SelectedValue's XAML.  Both properties are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

My filtering looks like this in the code behind (which is being fired by the Target_Updated and SelectionChanged events):

```
if (combobox.SelectedValue != null)
                base.ItemsSource = combobox.ItemsSource.Cast<IEntity2>().Where(x => (bool)x.Fields["IsActive"].CurrentValue == true || x.Fields[combobox.SelectedValuePath].CurrentValue.ToString() == combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToList().AsEnumerable();
            else
                base.ItemsSource = combobox.ItemsSource.Cast<IEntity2>().Where(x => (bool)x.Fields["IsActive"].CurrentValue == true).ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

Two XAML samples SelectedValue bindings: The first one works, the second does not.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding MyVm.ObjectId, Converter={StaticResource IntToShortConverter}}"

SelectedValue="{Binding MyVm.AnotherObjectId}"
```

Something else is happening with the binding using the converter that is causing all of this to work.  Is there another property or event I can use on the combobox to pick this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't the converter.  In the second line of sample XAML, the ItemsSource was defined first or to the left of the SelectedValue binding.  The top sample XAML had the ItemsSource defined second or to the right.

After modifying the order by defining the SelectedValue before the ItemsSource "left-to-right" it works flawlessly.  Not the optimal answer, since this means have to keep this in mind when writing the XAML...